# CSS from database is being ignored

Tags: google-app-engine

I usually use GAE static css directories which work fine. To speed testing (no need to deploy just for static file updates), I did a quick setup where the html, js, and css files load as entities, and are delivered from the DB by the on-line handler rather than as static files. Works great for .html and .js files, but the browser ignores the css  when it is served by the on-line handler. I am including `self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/css'` in the response. Below are the two log entries for each type of call. Something is different when the non-static file is delivered. Can I work around this??

```
dev_appserver.py:3103] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

dev_appserver.py:3103] "GET /getTest/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: If you go to the db-served one directly in your browser, what do you see? What does the Firebug/Dev Tools network tab report as the content type?

Comment: Do you also have this issue in production after deploying your application?

Answer (score 0):

Very embarrassing - as per Daniel I had failed to deploy the version setting Content-type. To derive some value from this fubar question: If you are loading css directly from the DB remember to use:

```
self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = 'text/css'
```

Apologies -stevep

Comment: don't forget to accept your own answer so others don't see it as unanswered :P